# ¿Cómo habilitar la edición de una fila en DataGridView? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Verán, estoy desarrollando el siguiente software:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo hacer es de que cuando se presione el botón MODIFICAR de una determinada fila, que solamente esa fila se habilite para su edición, las demás filas no deben poder modificarse a menos que se presione el botón MODIFICAR. Mientras no se presione ese botón ninguna fila debe poder modificarse. Creo que ya entienden que es lo que quiero hacer. Para ello hice el siguiente código pero no funciona:

```
private void DGVMedicos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if(senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if(DGVMedicos[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.Equals("MODIFICAR")) //EN ESTA CONDICION ES DONDE SE HACE UN EQUIVALENTE A SI SE HIZO CLICK EN EL BOTON MODIFICAR
            {
                //DGVMedicos.ReadOnly = false;
                DGVMedicos.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
                DGVMedicos.CurrentRow.ReadOnly = false;
            } else
            {
                //ESTA CONDICION ES PARA EL OTRO BOTON DE ELIMINAR, NO SE MOLESTEN A ANALIZAR ESTA PARTE YA QUE YA ES FUNCIONAL.
                if (MessageBox.Show("¿Esta seguro de eliminar el registro?", "SIET", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    int id = (int)DGVMedicos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value;
                    string ci = DGVMedicos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    string apellido = DGVMedicos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    string nombre = DGVMedicos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    int sexo = DGVMedicos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString().Equals("MASCULINO") ? 1 : 0;
                    bool activo = true;
                    Medico medico = new Medico(id, ci, apellido, nombre, sexo, activo);
                    presenterGestionMedicos.deleteMedico(medico);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo te recomiendo es que al seleccionar una fila del datagridView mandes los datos de los registros seleccionados a textBox.
Algo asi:

```
'Obtén la posición de la columna llamada CorreoDeUsuario
Dim ColumnaCorreo As Integer
ColumnaCorreo = Datagridview1.Columns("CorreoDeUsuario").Index

'Obtén el número de la fila que se seleccionó en el Datagridview
Dim FilaActual As Integer
FilaActual = Datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index

'Mostrar en el cuadro de texto o TextBox1 en valor de la columna CorreoDeUsuario del usuario seleccionado
TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(FilaActual).Cells(ColumnaNombre).Value
```

Y de acuerdo a la informacion de los texBox actualizas tu contenido.